# Why does "==" sometimes work with String.trim?

Tags: java, string

I have the following code

```
public static void main(String... args) {

    String s = "abc";
    System.out.println(s.hashCode());
    String s1 = " abc ";
    System.out.println(s1.hashCode());
    String s2 = s.trim();
    System.out.println(s2.hashCode());
    String s3 = s1.trim();
    System.out.println(s3.hashCode());
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(s == s1);
    System.out.println(s == s2);
    System.out.println(s == s3);
}
```

OP:

```
96354
32539678
96354
96354

false   -- Correct
true    -- This means s and s2 are references to the same String object "abc" .
false   -- s3=s1.trim()... which means s3="abc" yet s==s3 fails.. If the above conditon were to be considered (s==s2 is true..) , this should also be true..
```

Why am i getting "false" when i check s==s3 ?..

Comment: @JigarJoshi - I doubt if its a duplicate. The OP knows about when to use `==` and `equals()`. This question is about a specific case, where `==` behaves differently for different situations.

Comment: @R.J Then this question shouldn't exist.. (or the OP just needs to review some of the other duplicates on the topic)

Comment: @user2864740 - I disagree with you on that. It is a good question asking a very specific doubt. I don't see why this shouldn't exist. Voting to re-open

Comment: Dont have enough reputations - otherwise would have voted to open this ques. its seriously not a duplicate and is a good question as well

Comment: I'm with R.J. this is not duplicate

Comment: I still think it's a self-answered question, but at least now it doesn't have a terribly horrible title so I'll give it a reopen vote ... note sure how such a titled (as it originally was) question can be "good".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public String trim() {
    int len = value.length;
    int st = 0;
    char[] val = value;    /* avoid getfield opcode */

    while ((st < len) && (val[st] <= ' ')) {
        st++;
    }
    while ((st < len) && (val[len - 1] <= ' ')) {
        len--;
    }
    return ((st > 0) || (len < value.length)) ? substring(st, len) : this;
}
```

As you can see in your case(`System.out.println(s == s2);`) `this` is returned which is pointing to same reference which is why you get true.

Answer (score 5):

becuase `s1.trim()` will return a new instance. Strings are immutable so every time a function applied on Strings then a new instance will be returned and You are using `==` which compares the instance equality

**Edit:**  As suggested By Chris Hayes and R.J.

`trim` is smart and returns `this` if there's no whitespace to trim. So in second case you have ' abc ' white spaces so in this case it is not returning `this` but a new instance of string.

source code of [trim method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.trim%28%29)

Comment: @RJ Because `trim` is smart and returns `this` if there's no whitespace to trim. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.trim%28%29

Comment: @RJ It probably would have saved you a great deal of grief to have been more explicit in the first comment. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at `String.trim` you'll see that it eventually calls `String.substring` which in turn returns `new String(...)` if the string is getting actually trimmed. That's why `==` fails.

Answer (score 1):

see in documentation - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim() -

`A copy of this string with leading and trailing white space removed, or this string if it has no leading or trailing white space.`

when the string is staying the same it returns the string given itself.

Comment: Yes.. I know that i should use .equals() my question is why does s1.trim() return a new object when s.trim() doesnt ?

Answer (score 1):

The Java 7 source code for java.lang.String.trim() (from the installed JDK) is:

```
public String trim() {
    int len = value.length;
    int st = 0;
    char[] val = value;    /* avoid getfield opcode */

    while ((st < len) && (val[st] <= ' ')) {
        st++;
    }
    while ((st < len) && (val[len - 1] <= ' ')) {
        len--;
    }
    return ((st > 0) || (len < value.length)) ? substring(st, len) : this;
}
```

The return statement states that if there is no change to the String being trimmed, then this is returned, hence s == s2:

```
String s = "abc";
String s2 = s.trim();
System.out.println(s == s2); // is true
```

When the String being trimmed needs to be trimmed, java.lang.String.substring() is called.  The source code for substring() in Java 7 is:

```
public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex) {
    if (beginIndex < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(beginIndex);
    }
    if (endIndex > value.length) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(endIndex);
    }
    int subLen = endIndex - beginIndex;
    if (subLen < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(subLen);
    }
    return ((beginIndex == 0) && (endIndex == value.length)) ? this
            : new String(value, beginIndex, subLen);
}
```

When the String being trimmed has to be trimmed, then substring() returns a new String:

```
new String(value, beginIndex, subLen)
```

This is why s != s3:

```
String s = "abc";
String s1 = " abc ";
String s3 = s1.trim();
System.out.println(s == s3); // is false
```

Source code for this answer is available on GitHub [here](https://github.com/stevendoolan/stackoverflow/blob/master/stringequals/src/Example.java).